# Regex c# property to typescript field

Tags: c#, regex, typescript

I would like to create a regex that replaces c# properties in typescript fields:

`public int ItemOfferId { get; set; }` would become `itemOffer: int;`

I'm stuck in the first step: I just want to remove the prefix `public int` and the suffix `{ get; set; }` in  a **single** regex. Expected : `ItemOfferId`

For the moment I have `(public ([a-z]+) (?=([A-Za-z]+))\w+ { get; set; })` which is giving me `ItemOfferId` in group3 but I wonder how to ignore it, like creating a hole?

Comment: Do you want to create typescript interfaces/classes based on C# classes ? Because there are better ways to do that...

Comment: Based on the bare minimum of what you're asking using regex, I would use this instead: `public\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*\{\s*get;\s*set;\s*\}` with the following substitution: `$2: $1;`. This does exactly what you're asking of regex, but I would definitely agree with @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that there is probably a better way to go about this.

Comment: Why not to use Reflections? You can do it in post-build script.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes that's what I want. I have models in backend fetching by frontEnd and I want to have the same object definition... What would be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate typescript interfaces based on your C# types I would recommend [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/). I use in my current project with good results. It uses T4 templates which you can customize to generate Typescript  definitions, I found it sufficiently customizable and very useful.

Comment: Thanks you! you were right this is a better option!

Comment: @user8019820 Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to point out that maybe regexing code into code is a bad idea but you can do it like this:

Replace

`[public|private|internal]{0,}\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s{0,}\{\s{0,}get\s{0,};\s{0,}set\s{0,};\s{0,}\}`

with

`$2: $1`

Explanation: 
https://regex101.com/r/TCKchv/2

Comment: I just want to do CTRL-H (replace) in visual studio code using a regex expression to go faster. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

`public ((?!\s).)+|{ get; set; }`